# Cannot get createRedirects working with Docusaurus

Tags: javascript, redirect, docusaurus

I am working to put my docusaurs site into "docs only mode" and switch all files to be in the root directory instead of /docs. I have that part done, but I also want to redirect the existing paths to the new locations, for example if the old path was /docs/pricing, I want to redirect the user to just /pricing. If I use the [createRedirects function per the documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects#ex-config), the redirects will not work.

I can get simple redirects working if I put each existing path/page in as an entry in the redirects array, but that will be tedious and not managable in the long term. If I try and use the createRedirects example in the docs to redirect anything in /docs to go find the same page in / it will not work. Here is the code I have tried:

```
        createRedirects(existingPath) {
          if (existingPath.includes('/')) {
            // Redirect from /docs/X to /X
            return [
              existingPath.replace('/docs', '/'),
            ];
          }
          return undefined; // Return a falsy value: no redirect created
        },
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two issues here:

1. You are using `replace` in the "wrong" direction. You want to take every *existing* route (in your case, every route), and add `/docs` it, not the other way around.
2. using `replace` then would not make sense as you don't want to replace every `/`.

So this should work:

```
createRedirects(existingPath) {
          return [
            '/docs' + existingPath
          ];
        },
```

Comment: I am not trying to add /docs. I am trying to remove it. So, when a request comes in for /docs/mypage, I want it redirected to just /mypage.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this means you want to take the existing path, for example `/mypage`, and then create a redirect for it - which means a redirect entry of `/docs/mypage` to `/mypage`. This is what my code above does :)